# Modern state machine

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Based on previous examples and code submitted, I wrote this simple state machine, let me know if you have other suggests on optimizations potentially algorithmic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <string_view>

enum AccountTypes
{
    Red,
    Silver,
    Gold,
    AccountTypesNum
};
class Account
{
public:
    Account(std::string owner)
        : owner_{std::move(owner)},

          withDrawFunctrs_{// red

                           [this](double amount)
                           {
                               double newAmount = amount + serviceFee_;
                               if (balance_ - newAmount < lowerLimit_)
                               {
                                   std::cout << "No funds available for withdrawal!\n";
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   balance_ -= newAmount;
                               }
                           },
                           [this](double amount) // silver
                           { balance_ -= amount; },
                           [this](double amount) //gold
                           { balance_ -= amount; }},

          stateChangeFunctrs_{

              [this]() //red
              {
                  if (balance_ > upperLimit_)
                  {
                      accountType_ = Silver;
                      unpack();
                  }
              },
              [this]() // silver
              {
                  if (balance_ < lowerLimit_)
                  {
                      accountType_ = Red;
                      unpack();
                  }
                  else if (balance_ > upperLimit_)
                  {
                      accountType_ = Gold;
                      unpack();
                  }
              },
              [this]() //gold
              {
                  if (balance_ < 0.0)
                  {
                      accountType_ = Red;
                      unpack();
                  }
                  else if (balance_ < lowerLimit_)
                  {
                      accountType_ = Silver;
                      unpack();
                  }
                  else if (balance_ > upperLimit_)
                  {
                      std::cout << "Your account is too big now. Please consider using other account types\n";
                  }
              }},

          accountType_{Silver}
    {
        unpack();
    }
    void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance_ += amount;
        stateChangeFunctrs_[accountType_]();
        print("Deposited", amount);
    }
    void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        withDrawFunctrs_[accountType_](amount);
        stateChangeFunctrs_[accountType_]();
        print("Withdrew", amount);
    }
    void payInterest()
    {
        balance_ = balance_ * (interest_ / 100);
        stateChangeFunctrs_[accountType_]();
    }

private:
    void print(std::string_view action, double amount)
    {
        std::cout << action << " $" << amount << '\n';
        std::cout << "Balance   $" << balance_ << '\n';
        std::cout << "Status    " << stateName_ << '\n';
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    static inline std::unordered_map<AccountTypes, std::tuple<double, double, double, double, std::string_view>> thresholds_ // reference data
        {
            //     intrest, lower, upper, service_fee
            {Red, {0.0, -100.0, 0.0, 15.0, "Red"}},
            {Silver, {1.0, 0.0, 1000.0, 0, "Silver"}},
            {Gold, {5.0, 1000.0, 1000'000.0, 0, "Gold"}}};
    void unpack()
    {
        std::tie(interest_, lowerLimit_, upperLimit_, serviceFee_, stateName_) = thresholds_[accountType_];
    }

    std::string owner_;

    double balance_;
    double interest_;
    double lowerLimit_;
    double upperLimit_;
    double serviceFee_;
    using ActionCallBack = std::array<std::function<void(double)>, AccountTypesNum>;
    using VoidCallBack = std::array<std::function<void()>, AccountTypesNum>;
    ActionCallBack withDrawFunctrs_;
    VoidCallBack stateChangeFunctrs_;
    AccountTypes accountType_;
    std::string_view stateName_;
};
int main()
{
    Account account("Dr. Who");
    account.withdraw(10.00);
    account.withdraw(30.00);
    account.withdraw(70.00);
    account.deposit(234.00);
    account.deposit(5000.00);
    account.withdraw(5200.00);
    account.deposit(1500.00);
    account.deposit(1.00);
    account.withdraw(1200.00);
    account.deposit(10001200.00);
    account.deposit(1200.00);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Move `AccountType` into `Account`

You can nest `namespace`s, `class`es and `enum`s in C++. Consider writing:

```
class Acount {
    enum Type {
        Red,
        …
    };
    …
};
```

## Keep related data together in a `struct`

`thresholds_` is a map from account type to a tuple of stuff. The problem with `std::tuple` is that it's harder to get data into and out of it, and the elements of the tuple don't have a name, so you have to be very careful and remember the correct order all the time.

Furthermore, given an account type, you also have a withdrawal function and a state change function. It would be nice of those were not in separate arrays, because now you have to ensure all those containers have the same ordering.

Using `std::function` to store the withdrawal and state change functions is one way to store them into a map or an array, but it makes the code more messy than necessary. I think [pointers to member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) are a better choice here.

Consider this instead:

```
class Account {
    …
    void withdraw_red(double amount) {
        double newAmount = amount + state_[accountType_].serviceFee;
        …
    }

    void withdraw_other(double amount) {
        balance_ -= amount;
    }

    void change_red() {
        if (balance_ > state_[accountType_].upperLimit)
            accountType_ = Silver;
    }
    …
    struct State {
        std::string name;
        double interest;
        double lowerLimit;
        double upperLimit;
        double serviceFee;
        void (Account::* withdraw)(double);
        void (Account::* change)();
    };

    static inline const State states_[] = {
        {"Red",    0.0, -100.0,         0.0, 15.0,
                   &Account::withdraw_red,   &Account::change_red)},
        {"Silver", 1.0,    0.0,      1000.0,    0,
                   &Account::withdraw_other, &Account::change_silver)},
        {"Gold",   5.0, 1000.0, 1000'0000.0,    0,
                   &Account::withdraw_other, &Account::change_gold)},
    };
    …
public:
    …
    void withdraw(double amount) {
        (this->*states_[accountType_].withdraw)(amount);
        (this->*states_[accountType_].change)();
        print("Withdrew", amount);
    }
};
```

## Avoid storing data unnecessarily

You have the account limits in a map, but you also copy that into non-`static` member variables everytime you change the account type. But that is duplicating the data that was already there, so you are using more memory than necessary. And now you had to spend a lot of effort trying to keep things in sync by calling `unpack()` every time you change the account type. It is easy to forget to do that in one place, and then you'll have a program that seems to be working fine, but actually has a bug.

In the above example I just accessed `states_[accountType_]` everywhere. If you think that's a lot to type, you could create a helper function for that:

```
State& state() const {
    return states_[accountType_];
}
```

## Do you need a state machine?

This particular program doesn't need to be implemented as a state machine. I would keep the array of properties for each account type, like the interest rate and the limits, but I would just put all the logic into a few functions. Most of it is just checking against the `upperLimit` and `lowerLimit` of an account type, and adjusting the type accordingly. Note that you can modify the value of an `enum` variable programmatically:

```
// raise type:
accountType_ = Type(int(accountType_) + 1);
// lower type:
accountType_ = Type(int(accountType_) - 1);
```

Of course, care should be taken that the enum values are consecutive, and that you don't raise or lower it to a non-existing value. You could also consider not using an `enum` type to hold the account type, just use an integer.

## Remove the service fee

This is a terrible practice, especially if you only charge it for accounts with low funds.

Comment: Thank you for your input, indeed this is a different way of looking to the problem. 
You said " The problem with std::tuple it's harder to get data into and out of it,", from which prospective harder?

Another point you said "Most of it is just checking against the upperLimit and lowerLimit of", aren’t all state machines like that?

BTW, regarding "Remove the service fee", I got this example from the internet, and modified it a bit, not charging anything

Comment: Well in the end everything is a state machine one way or another. But we usually talk about an implementation of a state machine in code when you have explicit functions (or perhaps `case` statements in a `switch) for each state that in turn select the next state to go to, which is what you have with your `stateChangeFunctrs_`. If you have generic code like `if (balance_ < states_[accountType_].upperLimit_) accountType -= 1`, then you wouldn't call it a state machine, because it doesn't look like one.

Comment: As for the "service" fee, have a look at [Trevor Noah explaining overdraft fees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0tx5e5Aoqk).